# LocalStorage does not save after page refresh (React context)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, react-context

I am developing a context in which through a function I can send "pokemons" to a global array, and also send the information of this array to my localstorage so that it is saved in the browser, I managed to do that and the array items are in localstorage, but every time the site refreshes, localstorage goes back to the empty array.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import CatchContext from "./Context";


const CatchProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([], () => {
        const dataStorage = localStorage.getItem('pokemons');

        if (dataStorage) {
            return JSON.parse(dataStorage)
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    });
    
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('pokemons', JSON.stringify(pokemons));
    }, [pokemons]);

    const updatePokemons = (name) => {  
        const updatedPokemons = [...pokemons]; 
        const pokemonsIndex = pokemons.indexOf(name);
        if (pokemonsIndex >= 0) { 
            updatedPokemons.slice(pokemonsIndex, 1)    
        } else { 
            updatedPokemons.push(name) 
        };
        setPokemons(updatedPokemons) 
    }     
  
    const deletePokemon = async (name) => {   
      await pokemons.splice(pokemons.indexOf(toString(name)))
    }  


    return (
        <CatchContext.Provider value={{ pokemons: pokemons, updatePokemons: updatePokemons, deletePokemon: deletePokemon }}>
            {children}
        </CatchContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default CatchProvider;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `useState` doesn't take two arguments.

Instead of:

```
const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([], () => {
```

You want:

```
const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState(() => {
```

Comment: Delete pokemons? I didn't understand

Comment: Updated to show the diff

Comment: The second argument to `useState` was never being called because `useState` accepts a single argument (which can be either a value or a function)`

Comment: How does localStorage understand that what is being passed is an array if in useState in theory I am sending a function?

Comment: Because `useState` has a lazy api (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) where you pass `useState` a function, and the initial state is returned from that function. The `pokemons` value is an array whether you use the "normal" or "lazy" API.

Comment: One question, how can I remove a specific item from within that localStorage? The same way I would be removing an item from state ?

Comment: For example, if you go in my provider code to the "deletePokemon" function, I'm trying to create a function to remove an item from the array, but without success.

Comment: Every time you update your React state, can you also update local storage state?

Comment: Oh, you are already doing this with your useEffect, so that should work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to call `useEffect` on initial render so you can make use of `refs` for this

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

// other code....


const didMount = useRef(false);

 useEffect(() => {
       if (didMount.current) {
        localStorage.setItem('pokemons', JSON.stringify(pokemons));
       } else {
      didMount.current = true;
      }
    }, [pokemons]);
```

Comment: I replaced it and basically got the same thing. The problem is not in getting the information and sending it to localStorage, the problem is that with each rendering localStorage receives an empty array. How can I make these items remain in localStorage even if the page is refreshed?